# Two dimensional array 4x4, product of diagonals?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to take the product of all of the diagonal numbers in a 4x4 array. I know how to grab the numbers and print them, but I'm not sure how to take the product of them, how would I make it calculate the product of the 8 numbers?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
{
for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
{
    if (row==column || row == 3 - column)
    {
        double product = 1;
        product *= arr[row][column] 
        cout << product << ".";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Move `product` out of the for loops?

Comment: How would I grab the diagonals from the loops though, since I'm defining the specific numbers with the if statement?

Comment: Just move the the declaration.  Still do the multiplication in the if statement.

Comment: @КасимСал, you have 2 arrays lets say A and B, each array is a 4x4 array and you want to make the product of the diagonal nombers of array A with the diagonal numbers of array B,  is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to take the product of the numbers in Array A, then multiply that product by the product of the numbers in Array B. What Nathan said works, although in the script I run I see 8 diagonal elements, I don't see how there would be 7 since they don't seem to cross in center.

Comment: what do you mean by the product of the numbers in array A, the product of them with what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

- There are only `7` diagonal elements. You are counting the element in the centre of the matrix twice.
- you don't need to iterate the whole array in order to know about the diagonals. The diagonals have a nice property of `row == column` as you have observed and you only need to iterate along the diagonals.

To make things clearer and easier, calculate the two diagonal products separately:

```
double product = 1;
for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
    product *= arr[row][row]
}
for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
    product *= arr[row][4 - (row + 1)]
}
```

If you consider both entries in each row at a time, you'll have to also account for the fact that the middle element appears in both diagonals which makes the code unnecessarily messy.

Answer (score 0):

why you are defining the variable `product` inside the loop,thats why the previous data stored in the variable is lost when it goes out of scope.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double product = 1; // var product should be defined out of the loop

for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
{
for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
{
    if (row==column || row == 3 - column)
    {
        product *= arr[row][column];
    }
}
}

cout << product << ".";
```